# $\int_ \frac\pi6^\frac\pi2 \frac {3dx}{2\sin2x+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_  \frac\pi6^\frac\pi2 \frac {3dx}{2\sin2x+1}$$

I tried using this substitute:
$$(\tan x=u),(sin2x= \frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2x} =\frac{2u}{u^2+1}),   (dx=\frac{1}
{u^2+1}du)$$
and after long answer I get:

$$\frac{6+3\sqrt{3}}{6+4\sqrt{3}}.\ln(\frac{\tan x+2
-\sqrt{3}}{\tan x+2+\sqrt{3}})$$
and now I can not use $$F(\frac\pi2)-F(\frac\pi6)$$ because $$\tan(\frac\pi2)=\infty$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since
$$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\tan x +2-\sqrt{3}}{\tan x +2+\sqrt{3}}=\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1+\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{\tan x}}{1+\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{\tan x}}=1.$$
Then you can get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would do $u=\tan x$ too, and then your integral becomes$$\int_{1/\sqrt3}^\infty\frac3{t^2+4t+1}\,\mathrm dt.$$But$$\int\frac3{t^2+4t+1}\,\mathrm dt=\frac{\sqrt3}2\left(\log \left(-t+\sqrt{3}-2\right)-\log\left(t+\sqrt{3}+2\right)\right)$$and therefore\begin{multline}\int_{1/\sqrt3}^\infty\frac3{t^2+4t+1}\,\mathrm dt=\\=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt3}2\left(\log\left(-t+\sqrt{3}-2\right)-\log\left(t+\sqrt{3}+2\right)\right)-\\-\frac{\sqrt3}2\left(\log\left(-\frac1{\sqrt3}+\sqrt{3}-2\right)-\log\left(\frac1{\sqrt3}+\sqrt{3}+2\right)\right)=\\=\frac{\sqrt3}2\log\left(\frac{5+3\sqrt3}2\right).\end{multline}

Comment: How?: $$\int\frac3{t^2+4t+1}\,\mathrm dt=\frac{\log \left(-t+\sqrt{3}-2\right)-\log\left(t+\sqrt{3}+2\right)}{2\sqrt3}$$                                                                                               I used Partial Fractions in This situation

Comment: It follows from$$\frac3{t^2+4t+1}=\frac3{\left(t+2-\sqrt3\right)\left(t-2-\sqrt3\right)}=\frac{3/4}{t-2-\sqrt3}-\frac{3/4}{t+2-\sqrt3}.$$

Comment: It should be $$\frac3{\left(t+2+\sqrt3\right)\left(t+2-\sqrt3\right)}$$

Comment: Actually, it should be$$\frac3{t^2+4t+1}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\left(t-\sqrt{3}+2\right)}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\left(t+\sqrt{3}+2\right)}.$$I've edited my answer.

Comment: yes true I get it now